# есть ли альтернативный способ решения?

Tags: python

```
b=input("Введите слово: ")
n=len(b)
print(b)
p=0
for i in range(n):
if b[i]=="б":
p=p+1
ab=b.replace("б","ку")
print(p)
print(ab)
```

код должен изменять "б" на "ку" в слове что вводится с клавиатуры, и считать количество изменений.

Comment: Поставьте правильно табуляции, непонятно где цикл заканчивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то так:

```
b=input("Введите слово: ")
print(b.count("б"), b.replace("б", "ку"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [39]: word = input("Введите слово: ")
Введите слово: бабай-бабуин

In [40]: word_new = word.replace("б", "ку")

In [41]: print(word_new, len(word_new)-len(word))
куакуай-куакууин 4
```